# PHP preg_replace guids over multiple lines

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Hi there regex wizards!,

I have a document with multiple guids spread over multiple lines. I need to replace these guids with content from a file who's name is the found guid. I've tried this:

```
preg_replace('/^[a-f\d]{8}(-[a-f\d]{4}){4}[a-f\d]{8}$/i', file_get_contents("${1}.php"), $lines);
```

but it fails to find guids (and thus, also complains about ${1} not being found).

here is the multi-line string:

```
"
// Code in page

 //Run requested command: 
37906e3a-62f3-4d83-a8e0-9ad64a6a5228
de2dd82d-df13-4a8f-a760-cbc6e3db29d0

// bindings from HTML
af6236de-cf5d-447b-a9d5-28549aebd0fa
"
```

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Avi

Comment: `preg_replace_callback('/^(?:\s?[a-f\d]){8}\s?(?:-(?:\s?[a-f\d]){4}){4}(?:\s?[a-f\d]){8}$/mi', function($m) { return file_get_contents(preg_replace("~\s+~", "", $m[0]) . ".php"); }, $lines);`? See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8PUpUy/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace_callback(
  '/^(?:\s?[a-f\d]){8}\s?(?:-(?:\s?[a-f\d]){4}){4}(?:\s?[a-f\d]){8}$/mi', 
  function($m) { 
    return file_get_contents(preg_replace("~\s+~", "", $m[0]) . ".php"); 
  },
  $lines
);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8PUpUy/1).

The `\s?` inside the pattern allows matching an optional whitespace anywhere in between each char of a match. Also, with regard to the regex pattern, you need to use `m` flag to make `^` and `$` match line boundaries (start/end of the line, not just start/end of the whole string).

You can't pass `${1}` into a function within `preg_replace` replacement argument, you need a `preg_replace_callback` so that the match could be evaluated before passing it to a function.